# Transactions in while loop in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers, transactions

An error occurs while rollback:

> Msg 6401, Level 16, State 1, Procedure our_trigger, Line 76
>   Cannot roll back t1. No transaction or savepoint of that name was found.

And here is the SQL code in the trigger

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [DOCSADM].[our_trigger]
ON [DOCSADM].[PROFILE]
FOR UPDATE, INSERT
AS
    DECLARE @DocSystemId AS INTEGER
    DECLARE @docNumber AS INTEGER
    DECLARE @lastUsedSystemId AS INTEGER
    DECLARE @itemType AS VARCHAR(1) --dm10 
    DECLARE @manualBarcode AS VARCHAR (50)
    DECLARE @oldBarcodeFK AS INTEGER
    --user typed barcode, it must be inserted/UPDATED into pd_barcode table
    DECLARE @COUNTEXISTINGBARCODE AS INTEGER

    SET nocount ON;

    BEGIN
        DECLARE activity_cursor CURSOR local FOR
            SELECT 
                system_id, docnumber,
                a_doc_barcode, pd_doc_barcode, item_type
            FROM  
                inserted

        --find the last used systemid  
        SELECT @lastUsedSystemId = lastkey
        FROM docsadm.seq_systemkey

        OPEN activity_cursor

        FETCH next FROM activity_cursor INTO @DocSystemId, @docNumber, @manualBarcode, @oldBarcodeFK, @itemtype

        WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
        BEGIN
            IF (( @itemType = 'M' OR @itemType = 'P' ))
                --FIND IF IT EXISTS ALREADY A BARCODE
                SELECT @COUNTEXISTINGBARCODE = COUNT(*)
                FROM docsadm.pd_barcode
                WHERE pd_barcode = @manualBarcode

                IF (@COUNTEXISTINGBARCODE = 0)-- THERE IS NO EXISTING BARCODE
                     DECLARE @barcodeSystemId AS INTEGER = 0

                BEGIN TRANSACTION t1
                BEGIN TRY
                    -- get next sys id    
                    EXECUTE [DOCSADM].[Sp_nextkey] 'SYSTEMKEY'

                    SELECT @barcodeSystemId = lastkey
                    FROM docsadm.seq_systemkey

                    INSERT INTO docsadm.pd_barcode
                    VALUES (@manualBarcode, @barcodeSystemId, 'D', NULL, NULL, 'Y', NULL, NULL)

                    UPDATE docsadm.profile
                    SET pd_doc_barcode = @barcodeSystemId
                    WHERE docnumber = @docNumber

                    COMMIT TRANSACTION t1
                END TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION t1
                END CATCH
            END

            IF (@COUNTEXISTINGBARCODE <> 0)
               --YES THERE IS AT LEAST ONE BARCODE
            BEGIN
                SELECT TOP 1 @barcodeSystemId = system_id
                FROM docsadm.pd_barcode
                WHERE pd_barcode = @manualBarcode

                BEGIN TRANSACTION t1
                BEGIN TRY
                    --update profile's new barcode reference
                    UPDATE docsadm.profile
                    SET pd_doc_barcode = @barcodeSystemId
                    WHERE docnumber = @docNumber

                    UPDATE docsadm.pd_barcode
                    SET pd_doc_bcode_used = 'Y'
                    WHERE system_id = @barcodeSystemId

                    IF (@oldBarcodeFK <> 0)
                    BEGIN
                        --update old barcode as not used!
                        UPDATE docsadm.pd_barcode
                        SET pd_doc_bcode_used = 'N'
                        WHERE system_id = @oldBarcodeFK
                    END

                    COMMIT TRANSACTION t1
                END TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION t1
                END CATCH
                END

                FETCH next FROM activity_cursor INTO @DocSystemId, @docNumber, @manualBarcode, @oldBarcodeFK, @itemtype
            END

            CLOSE activity_cursor
            DEALLOCATE activity_cursor
      END
```

The error comes from here

```
  BEGIN CATCH
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION t1
  END CATCH
```

I tried to save trans but i got the same error. I also begin a trans before the loop but the message occured.

Comment: **OH GOSH!** A trigger should be **very nimble and FAST** - and it should **MOST DEFINITELY** not contain cursors which are the devil in terms of performance ....

Comment: @marc_s thank you for your answer. this trigger was made our previous developer and have no time to change now :)

Comment: Also, you're already running in the context of a transaction (the one that protects the `UPDATE` or `INSERT` that caused the trigger to fire). You shouldn't be creating "nested" transactions and should only `ROLLBACK` if you want the original `INSERT`/`UPDATE` to be rolled back - definitely not in a *loop*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, then we should not use cursor?

Comment: Yeah this needs a complete 100% rewrite. Nested transactions are a myth. They do NOT do what it seems like they should at all. And transactions in a trigger are a sign that something is very very wrong. From here it looks like the only real reason this is done in a cursor is because of the sp_getNetKey procedure which probably needs to be visited because that type of key generation is fraught with errors.

Comment: You said you don't have to time to change this now. I would ask when are you going to schedule time to fix this because it desperately needs the time.

Comment: @SeanLange, our customer is waiting now. If we could provide a quick and dirty Solution for now, it would be good

Comment: The quick and dirty solution is to get rid of all those transactions in your trigger. But you really need to schedule some time to fix this because it is awful.

Comment: @SeanLange, it seems we have to do that :)

Comment: You have no time to change it, but you are asking for an answer on how to change it. So you surely have time to change it if you are here asking for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This error says you tried to Commit or Rollback a transaction which does not exist. So, Before ROLLBACK check whether there exists an uncommitted transaction. Like this

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT>0
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```